# Google App Engine - Download Entire Live Application To Local

Tags: google-app-engine

Recently, I upload the web application in my local to Google App Engine

```
c:\LocalProject>c:\appengine-java-sdk-1.2.2\bin\appcfg.cmd update .
```

Unfortunately, I accidental delete the whole folder "LocalProject" in my local disk. Is it possible that I can recover all my stuff, by downloading from Google App Engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There are libraries you can include with your app to make the source code downloadable, but if you didn't do so when you uploaded your app, there's no way to download the source code.

Answer (score 11):

app engine actually recently added the ability for the developer who uploaded a given app version to download its source code:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Source_Code

Answer (score 4):

This is what source code management systems like Subversion and Git are for.  You should be using one, even for your home projects.