# how to get code from google appengine project?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google App Engine - Download Entire Live Application To Local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508266/google-app-engine-download-entire-live-application-to-local)

created and uploaded a java project to google appengine. now i lost the local folder which contained the project files. How to get the project files from google appengine ?

Comment: Note that while there may be a way to download what got uploaded to app engine, in the case of Java that is not your source code (but the compiled classes).

Comment: As an aside, grab yourself a github.com account (or equivalent) and learn to use it. Microsoft Word taught me this mantra many years ago, "save early, save often".

Comment: If you can download the compiled classes (but not the source code as I suspect), then you can use a Java decompiler to at least have a chance at getting your source code back.  See this thread for options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353/is-jad-the-best-java-decompiler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We recently added limited support for [downloading sourcecode in Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Source_Code), but because the Java runtime only uploads your compiled class files, there is no equivalent feature for Java. You shouldn't rely on App Engine to preserve your code - you need to use your own backup or version control system.

Comment: you can now http://www.labnol.org/software/download-appengine-files/19348/